# Attribute value give undefined when use this in foreach

Tags: jquery, foreach, this

I have few fields with a custom attribute `default`. when i click on a button with id `reset`, I want to change value of all the fields with class `afield` to its default.

Sample fields are,

```
<input type="text" class="afield" id="field1" default="10" value="10" />
<input type="text" class="afield" id="field2" default="20" value="20" />
```

Following code changes all fields' value to `undefined`,

```
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var afields = $('.afield')
   $.each(afields ,function(){ 
         this.value = this['default']; 
   });
});
```

But when I use the `id` to get the element and change the value it works fine. Code follows,

```
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var afields = $('.afield')
   $.each(afields ,function(){ 
         var ele =  $('#'+this.id)
         var defaultval = ele.attr('default')
         ele.val(defaultval)
   });
});
```

Why the first approach gives `undefined` as default value ?
Is there any way I can make use of `this` object inside loop and achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried in first example $(this).val($(this).attr('default')) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that "this" in jQuery each is HTML element, so to retrieve custom [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) value you should rewrite your example to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var afields = $('.afield')
   $.each(afields ,function(){ 
         this.value = this.attributes.default.value; 
   });
});
```

Once again check the docs ([HTML DOM Element attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes))

or since you use jQuery, you may not overcomplicate things, and just use

```
$(this).val($(this).attr('default'))
```

Comment: Thank you @2oppin

Comment: I used `this.value = $(this).attr('default')` and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following working snippet.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#reset', function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var afields = $('.afield')
   $.each(afields ,function(){ 
         this.value = $(this).attr("default"); 
   });
});
```

```html
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="afield" id="field1" default="10"  />
<input type="text" class="afield" id="field2" default="20"  />
<input type="button" id="reset" value ="Reset"/>
```

Comment: Thank you @Nitin.